# Set Object's attributes on its creation

Tags: java, swing

I sometimes see code like this:

```
new myJFrame().setVisible(true);
```

I don't exactly know how it works, but it actually creates a `myJFrame` and sets it visible, as an alternative to setting it visible on its constructor.

What I would like to know is if there would be a way to do this on a JMenuItem or JButton to automatically assign it an ActionListener without having to explicitly declaring it first, as in:

```
myJMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Item").addActionListener(myActionListener));
```

Which, as far as I've tried, doesn't work.

I don't exactly *need* it to work, I would just like to know if it is possible, for it would save me some good time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and simply put, a class either supports it or not, depending on how it's written.

The way it is done is simple:

```
public class Bar {

   private Set<Foo> foos;

   public Bar addFoo( Foo foo ) {
     this.foos.add( foo );
     return this;
   }
}
```

From this you can also see why it isn't possible to chain methods that weren't written this way.

Comment: You mean I can only do it with classes I've created and written this way? More specifically, can I do it with JMenuItem and / or with JButton? (For I don't know if I can see how they were created)

Comment: @AndréLeria Yes. Or classes that someone else wrote this way. Swing classes are usually not written in this style. But if you read the javadoc of a method, it should be obvious: if the documentation says the method returns `this`, then you can chain them. If it returns `void`, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed code won't work because `JMenuItem.addActionListener()` does not return anything (it's a void method), so there is nothing to pass as the argument to `JMenu.add()`.

In the first example, there is also nothing returned, but it doesn't matter.

As mentioned by @biziclop, in some styles of coding most methods return `this` so that they can be chained together.  For example, [Builders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which use a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) tend to do this.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, consider using the `JMenuItem` constructor that takes an `Action`:

```
myJMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Item") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: this isn't any alternative, answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

if you want nastiness you can do an anonymous extension of a non-final class and add an anonymous constructor to initialize stuff:

```
ArrayList ar=new ArrayList()  
    {
      {
        add(new Object());
      }
    };
```

Comment: If anything, this is even less readable than the non-chained version :)

Comment: yes but in some cases this is useful. For this case it is pure nastiness ;)

Comment: like for example adding tons of items to a menu , or initializing an arraylist or hashmap with many items.